# Error while accessing the Parameter Store strings from AWS lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-parameter-store

I am using the Parameter Store from AWS to store String parameter values.
I am using the following code while fetching the Params from the Lambda function:

```
const ssm = require('aws-sdk/clients/ssm');
const getConfig = (prefix) => {
  return ssm.getParameter({ Name: `/${prefix}/config`}).promise()
    .then(resp => JSON.parse(resp.Parameter.Value))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
};
```

But I am constantly getting the following error while running the Lambda from the AWS Console:

```
ERROR   AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::XXX:assumed-role/lambdaExecutionRole is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParameter on resource: arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:XXX:parameter/get/getValue
```

I tried to add the Administrator access to the role: lambdaExecutionRole, but now getting this error:

```
ERROR   SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at /var/task/myFile.js:2:955529
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Runtime.e.handler (/var/task/myFile.js:2:1065241)
```

I have even tried to add the ssm permissions following this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-paramstore-access.html):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "GetParam1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
         },
         "Action": "ssm:GetParameter",
         "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
- An error occurred: AssumeRole policy may only specify STS AssumeRole actions.
- An error occurred: Has prohibited field Resource
```

Any Idea what I might be missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The action is `ssm:GetParameter` but you're policy has `ssm:GetParameters`.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I corrected it but same issue again

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR   SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0

when you add `Administrator` permissions tells information you are getting from the parameter store and passing eventually to `JSON.parse` with `resp.Parameter.Value` is not proper.

Your policy as well is wrong, you are mixing `IAM Policy` with `Trust Policy`. They should be separately defined.

[Roles terms and concepts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html)

**Trust Policy** for your lambda `IAM Role`

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

*IAM Policy for Lambda IAM Role** to allow access to SSM Parameter Store**

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "GetParam1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": "ssm:GetParameter",
         "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

That's the reason for these errors

> - An error occurred: AssumeRole policy may only specify STS AssumeRole actions.
> - An error occurred: Has prohibited field Resource